# django-allauth - It is possible to implement a two steps registration?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've installed django-allauth but I need to costumize the signup process with a two steps sign up where the first page will collect the username, email, password and a custom user profile and the second page will handle a payment(paypal) subscription.

This is possible to implement using django-allauth?

Best Regards,
André

Answer (score 1):

So far the easiest solution for me was using @user_passes_test on all view functions, that in principle expect logged in user.  Your decorator should invoke the function, which checks if the second step of the setup has been completed.  If yes, it returns true, if not, redirects to the relevant form:

```
@user_passes_test(checkUser, "/signup/second-step")
def showSomeStuff(request):
    pass
```

Note, that this is actually not allauth specific in any way, this will work with any other form of user creation/registration.